# How to parse XML file using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse the following xml and get the value of metadata:description using php

I know how to get the value of title

```
$item_title = $x -> item($i) -> getElementsByTagName('title') -> item(0) -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue;
```

but can not use this way to get metadata:description

```
<item>
  <title>Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?</title>
  <metadata:title xmlns:metadata="http://search.cnbc.com/rss/2.0/modules/siteContentMetadata">Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?  06 Jan 2012</metadata:title>
  <description>Discussing whether the better than expected jobs number point to an economic rebound, and where to invest in this market, with Michael Farr, Farr, Miller, &amp; Washington president.</description>
  <metadata:description xmlns:metadata="http://search.cnbc.com/rss/2.0/modules/siteContentMetadata"><![CDATA[<div class="rss_image" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;"><img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="93" src="http://thumbnails.cnbc.com/VCPS/Y2012/M01D06/3000066213/6ED1-KR-Jobs_sm.jpg"></div><div class="rss_abstract" style="font:Arial 12px;width:100%;float:left;clear:both">Discussing whether the better than expected jobs number point to an economic rebound, and where to invest in this market, with Michael Farr, Farr, Miller, &amp; Washington president.</div>]]></metadata:description>
  <pubDate>Sat, 07 Jan 2012 00:24 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cnbc.com//id/15840232?video=3000066213&amp;play=1</guid>
  <link>http://www.cnbc.com//id/15840232?video=3000066213&amp;play=1</link>
</item>
```

---

Original xml file link

```
http://www.cnbc.com/id/19838222/device/rss/rss.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$xmlstr='<item>
<title>Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?</title>
<metadata:title xmlns:metadata="http://search.cnbc.com/rss/2.0/modules/siteContentMetadata">Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?  06 Jan 2012</metadata:title>
<description>Discussing whether the better than expected jobs number point to an economic rebound, and where to invest in this market, with Michael Farr, Farr, Miller, &amp; Washington president.</description>
<metadata:description xmlns:metadata="http://search.cnbc.com/rss/2.0/modules/siteContentMetadata"><![CDATA[<div class="rss_image" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;"><img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="93" src="http://thumbnails.cnbc.com/VCPS/Y2012/M01D06/3000066213/6ED1-KR-Jobs_sm.jpg"></div><div class="rss_abstract" style="font:Arial 12px;width:100%;float:left;clear:both">Discussing whether the better than expected jobs number point to an economic rebound, and where to invest in this market, with Michael Farr, Farr, Miller, &amp; Washington president.</div>]]></metadata:description>
<pubDate>Sat, 07 Jan 2012 00:24 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cnbc.com//id/15840232?video=3000066213&amp;play=1</guid>
<link>http://www.cnbc.com//id/15840232?video=3000066213&amp;play=1</link>
</item>';

$x= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $x->title;
$nss = $x->getNameSpaces(true);
$metadata = $x->children($nss['metadata']); 
echo $metadata->title, "\n";
echo $metadata->description, "\n";
```

Output

```
Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?Jobs: Bullish Economy Confirmed?  06 Jan 2012
<div class="rss_image" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;"><img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="93" src="http://thumbnails.cnbc.com/VCPS/Y2012/M01D06/3000066213/6ED1-KR-Jobs_sm.jpg"></div><div class="rss_abstract" style="font:Arial 12px;width:100%;float:left;clear:both">Discussing whether the better than expected jobs number point to an economic rebound, and where to invest in this market, with Michael Farr, Farr, Miller, &amp; Washington president.</div>
```

Comment: I try to parse this xml http://www.cnbc.com/id/19838222/device/rss/rss.xml , but get error when I use SimpleXMLElement. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Comment: 'String could not be parsed as XML' error shows when your XML input is empty or not in a correct format. please first check you input.