# How to parse xml with php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)
>   [How to parse XML file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775669/how-to-parse-xml-file-using-php)

i could not parse this xml... the real xml is [here](http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/sismo/zeqmap/xmlt/son24saat.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<eqlist>
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 18:35:13"  lokasyon="CAMONU-AKHISAR (MANİSA)                           İlksel" lat="38.9572"   lng="27.8965"   mag="2.9" Depth="5.0" />
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 18:54:09"  lokasyon="VAN GÖLÜ                                          İlksel" lat="38.7273"   lng="43.1598"   mag="2.3" Depth="2.1" />
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 21:00:49"  lokasyon="KUCUKESENCE-ERENLER (SAKARYA)                     İlksel" lat="40.7347"   lng="30.4742"   mag="1.9" Depth="4.4" />
</eqlist>
```

how can i parse it? the problem is coming from first two chars of the xml file which is running nice remote site's google map application. Look at that array

```
[0] => ÿþ<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? PHP has several extensions for XML parsing - SimpleXML, DOM, SAX...

Comment: Didn't you dare to google for `php xml`?

Comment: I think the answer may not be as simple as what you can find with a google for PHP XML.  Go look at the original document.  The author of this question just happened to choose lines that parse correctly.  The entire document does not!

Comment: It's not just the XML tag - the entire document has invisible characters.  You can detect this by using strlen() on any line.  If you count what you see, it will be a lot less than the values passed from strlen().  Recommend you contact the publisher and ask for information about the character encoding.  Also, read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML_Load_String.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_burhan.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

$xml = <<<ENDXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<eqlist>
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 18:35:13"  lokasyon="CAMONU-AKHISAR (MANISA)                           Ilksel" lat="38.9572"   lng="27.8965"   mag="2.9" Depth="5.0" />
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 18:54:09"  lokasyon="VAN GÖLÜ                                          Ilksel" lat="38.7273"   lng="43.1598"   mag="2.3" Depth="2.1" />
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 21:00:49"  lokasyon="KUCUKESENCE-ERENLER (SAKARYA)                     Ilksel" lat="40.7347"   lng="30.4742"   mag="1.9" Depth="4.4" />
</eqlist>
ENDXML;

// CONVERT TO AN OBJECT
$obj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);

// PARSE OUT SOME ATTRIBUTES
foreach ($obj as $quake)
{
    // ATTRIBUTE NAMES ARE CASE-SENSITIVE
    $loc = $quake->attributes()->lokasyon;
    $dep = $quake->attributes()->Depth;
    echo PHP_EOL . "$loc $dep";
}
```

Comment: Now, having looked at the original document, I see that there may be some invalid characters in the XML.  So it may be a character-set encoding issue.  When I try to use the original directly, it fails, however when I copy it into my text editor, some of the characters are converted (and it works).  You might want to try a different character encoding, such as utf-8

Comment: I think you need to go back to the origination of this document.  It appears to have something (maybe a byte-order mark) in the top two characters.  And Chrome thinks it's in Turkish and wants to translate it ;-)

Comment: thanks Ray, the orginal document has got xml bomb. i am trying to remove it.

Comment: I copied the document into TextPad and saved it.  That munged some of the characters.  Where is the document originated?

Comment: its Turkish. the real problem is how to parse orginal xml file from remote site.

Comment: the error is hapening from first two chars "ÿþ". look at the array [0] => ÿþ<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

Answer (score 1):

An object oriented way

```
$xml = <<<ENDXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<eqlist>
    <earhquake  name="2012.12.31 18:35:13" 
                lokasyon="CAMONU-AKHISAR (MANISA) Ilksel"
                lat="38.9572"
                lng="27.8965"   mag="2.9" Depth="5.0" />
    <!-- Etc... -->
</eqlist>
ENDXML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

Then you can use the various methods defined by [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). One of these methods that is useful for checking the validity with an XSD is `schemaValidate`

Comment: Try it on the original document linked with the question.  THe small sample works, but the original document does not.  Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 2 in /home/websitet/public_html/RAY_temp_burhan.php on line 65

Comment: @RayPaseur - Works find for me. As you noted you need to sort out the encoding issues.

Comment: Did you use the file at http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/sismo/zeqmap/xmlt/son24saat.xml ? How did you get it to work?

Comment: I couldn't fix it yet with using http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/sismo/zeqmap/xmlt/son24saat.xml